# Insert button into Google Docs with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome Extension, and instead of having a button in the browser toolbar, I would like to insert a button into Google Docs.

I can't figure out how to insert a button into the Google Docs toolbar using a Chrome Extension. Specifically, how do I inject the button into the Google Docs toolbar as opposed to creating a dialog box or something similar? (I know how to do the latter in my content.js file).

Here is a link to another Chrome Extension that injects a button into the Google Docs toolbar, as I am trying to do: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/draftback/nnajoiemfpldioamchanognpjmocgkbg?hl=en-US

Comment: Apps Script has absolutely nothing to do with Chrome Apps.

Comment: see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: @levi it will probably not works because google don't let extension inject script in Google sites pages

Comment: I know its possible somehow because (for example) this extension inserts a button into the Docs toolbar: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/draftback/nnajoiemfpldioamchanognpjmocgkbg?hl=en-US

Comment: Like I said, Apps Script has nothing to do with Chrome Apps or Chrome Extensions. Apps Script is a server-side extension, and Chrome Apps/Extenisons are client-side. Your example indeed adds a button, but has nothing to do with Apps Script. So what kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, the example I provided is a Chrome Extension (not Apps Script). My program is also a Chrome Extension (I edited my question to make that more clear). I do not understand how to add a button to Google Docs using a Chrome Extension - that is the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out by looking at the content.js file for the extension I linked to in the question.

Within the content.js file of your Chrome Extension, create a button and define the HTML for the button:

```
var $my_button = $('<div role="button" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard docs-titlebar-button">My button</div>');
```

The class definition uses Google Doc's CSS classes (which I found by inspecting the buttons I wanted to emulate) so that it blends in with the title bar.

Then, use ".prependTo" to inject the button into the Google Docs titlebar.

```
$my_button.prependTo($('.docs-titlebar-buttons'));
```

This created a nice button that looks like this:

[image: Google Docs Titlebar Button]